# Kubernetes - Unable to connect to a redis pod from another pod on the same cluster

Tags: redis, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-helm

Connection between pods on the same cluster is failing.

From what I understand, by default - the pods are exposed on the port specified in the yaml file. For example, I have configured my deployment file for redis as below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: REDIS_PASS
          value: '**None**'
        image: tutum/redis
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        name: redis
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Below is the deployment file for the pod where the container is trying to access redis:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jks
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: myappsecret
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: JOBQUEUE
          value: vae_jobqueue
        - name: PORT
          value: "80"
        image: repo.url
        name: jks
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-vol
            mountPath: /etc/sys0
      volumes:
        - name: config-vol
          configMap:
            name: config

      restartPolicy: Always
```

I did not create any service yet. But is it required? The pod is going to be accessed by another pod which is part of the same helm chart. With this setup,there are errors in the second pod which tries to access redis:

```
2018-11-21T16:12:31.939Z - [33mwarn[39m:  Error: Redis connection to redis:6379 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis redis:6379
    at errnoException (dns.js:27:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:78:26)
```

*How do I make sure that my pod is able to connect to the redis pod on port 6379?*

---- UPDATE ----

This is how my charts look like now:

```
# Source: mychartv2/templates/redis-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp-redis
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: redis
    port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
---
# Source: mychartv2/templates/redis-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: myapp-redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp-redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: REDIS_PASS
          value: '**None**'
        image: tutum/redis
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        name: redis
      restartPolicy: Always
---
# Source: mychartv2/templates/jks-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jks
  labels:
    app: myapp-jks
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp-jks
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: jkssecret
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: JOBQUEUE
          value: jks_jobqueue
        - name: PORT
          value: "80"
        image: repo.url
        name: jks
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-vol
            mountPath: /etc/sys0
      volumes:
        - name: config-vol
          configMap:
            name: jksconfig

      restartPolicy: Always
```

**Note**: I am using minikube as my kubernetes cluster

Comment: Can you provide the chart templates those you used?

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma Updated my question, just the two

Answer (score 3):

You'd need a [`Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to get access to the Redis pod. With your current resources `redis:6379` does just not exist, a Service with `metadata.name: redis` and the appropriate `spec.selector` would make it available.

Be aware the 2 deployments you posted have the same `metadata.labels.app` value of `myapp` so you'd have to change one to say `myapp-redis` for example so the service will target the right pods (with `metadata.name: myapp-redis` in that example) and not the pods from your HTTP application.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp-redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: REDIS_PASS
          value: '**None**'
        image: tutum/redis
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        name: redis
      restartPolicy: Always

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp-redis
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 6379
```

Also, you added the tag `kubernetes-helm` to your question, so if you are using Helm I'd highly recommend [this stable chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/redis): just install it with `helm install stable/redis` and you'll be able to access your Redis master with `redis-master:6379` and any read-only slave with `redis-slave:6379`. You can avoid having slaves if you don't need/want them, just go through [the configuration](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/redis#configuration) to know how.

Comment: I did manage to install only the master. But then my second pod tries to connect to  redis:6379 . How do I have the master configured for that? Also I would want one helm install to setup everything (including the redis), is that possible?

Comment: Great! `redis-master:6379` is the default "connection string / url" if you used the Helm chart mentioned, where `redis-master` is the name of the service created. If you changed the Helm release name or in doubt, grab the service name by `kubectl get services`, then update your code connecting to Redis with the appropriate url.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't create any service for `redis` pod, you need either (01) the pod dns name or (02) podIP, followed by port (6379) to connect to it. See [dns-pod-service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) for how to get the dns name for pod.

You can get the dns name in this format `<pod_name>.namespace.pod.cluster.local` and the connection uri is `<pod_name>.namespace.pod.cluster.local:6379`.

You can get the podIP from `.status.podIP` and the connection uri is `podIP:6379`.

In cluster the podIP may change for any reason. So it is not wise to use the podIP. It would be better if you create service and use it's dns name followed by the service port (in the case of following yaml it is 6379). We can create a service using following configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: redis # Actually, no port is needed.
    port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
```

**Update:**

However, you can check the redis connection by using `redis-cli` binary in your pod from which you want to check connection. If you have this `redis-cli`, then run `$ redis-cli -h <host>`, where

```
host = redis_service_host or pod_host or redis_servce_ip or pod_ip
```

Comment: I did try exactly as suggested. But still I get the same error that it is unable to connect. Is there a way I could check the connection to the redis pod from the other one?

Comment: There are things to know why its not happening. (01) `redis.conf`, (02) what you did i mean what command or whatever you used to cannect.

Comment: I meant, is it possible to go into the second pod and check the connection from there to the redis pod, to understand why it is not able to connect? I have updated my question with the charts I used

Comment: Updated my ans. check it

Comment: I went inside the the pod from which I want to check connection, and executed : `redis-cli -h redis` and I was able to connect: `redis:6379>` . Can't seem to understand why the container throws error though

Comment: Could you please show the command and the output (even if it is an error)?

Comment: I don't see an error when I exec `redis-cli -h redis` - it is connecting. The error I see in the logs of the pod is the one I have already pasted in the question

Comment: Also is there a way I could open connections to my localhost from this pod? I would want it to connect to the rabbitmq instance running on port 5672. At the moment - this too is failing

Comment: I also tried deploying both the containers in a single pod. Still the other container is complaining about not being able to access the redis pod with the same error message. I was thinking it shouldn't have this network issue if they are part of the same pod ?

Comment: Can you just use the serviceIP/podIP or both instead of the dns name as hostname (`redis`)? i.e. I mean use `podIP:6379`.

Comment: I am able to connect it inside the container : `redis-cli -h 172.21.0.6
172.21.0.6:6379>` But then I cannot change how the container calls the redis pod

Comment: Did it work or not? your comment is confusing to me.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. So when i go inside the container and try with the host ip - I am able to connect (similar to using dns - redis) But the container would always use redis - which I cannot change. So it is not working yet.

Comment: I think it is happening because in the source code of the binary of this container image is hard coded to use the url as `redis:6379`. And also once i had a problem while i was using dns instead of ip to create a redis cluster.

Comment: But what seems to be working fine when using docker should work here too I believe? And from inside the container if I could manually  use the dns name then I would expect it to work with the container too?